# Bug when returning to windows desktop MonoGame

Tags: c#, windows, monogame

I have created a monogame project for Windows but when I return on the windows desktop with alt + tab the game screen turns white and the icon disappears.

I only changed the screen size to 1920 x 1080, fullscreen = true and Windows.title = "The Last Dragon"

```
public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1920;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1080;
    graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
}
protected override void Initialize()
{
     // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
    this.Window.Title = "The Last Dragon";

    base.Initialize();
}
```

Comment: Its true the MonoGAme's latest news is the 2 march 2017 but i don't like Unity not because is a engine but because I can't create my engine ;)
With MonoGame I have a small engine ;)

Comment: Camilo,  Unity as more serious alternative to mono? Are you joking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When changing Settings of the GraphicsDeviceManager always make sure to apply those changes.
in your case graphics.ApplyChanges();

Comment: I have the same problem but its good I have edit my code ;) thanks